# Rss parsing in cakephp 2.0

Tags: rss, cakephp-2.0

I have followed the doc http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/helpers/rss.html but I can not get it working I have the following error

```
Missing Method in PostsController
Error: The action index.rss is not defined in controller PostsController
Error: Create PostsController::index.rss() in file: app\Controller\PostsController.php.
```

Comment: What URL are you visiting to produce this error?

Comment: http://localhost/myapp/posts/index.rss

Comment: Can you paste your code for the Posts controller? - Basically from the error, it has found the controller ok but hasn't successfully parsed the extension. This suggests there is either a problem with your routes.php file or the configuration of your controller.

Comment: My mistake, I was editing the wrong file. The doc works fine. Thanks anyway